# Encoding in MP3 in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ffmpeg, mp3

I am trying to encode my sample data to either mp3 directly or wav to mp3

I have written wav conversion code below:

```
 function encodeWAV(samples) {
                console.log("sample rate in encoded wav:"+sampleRate);
                let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
                let view = new DataView(buffer);

                /* RIFF identifier */
                writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
                /* RIFF chunk length */
                view.setUint32(4, 36 + samples.length * 2, true);
                /* RIFF type */
                writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
                /* format chunk identifier */
                writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
                /* format chunk length */
                view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
                /* sample format (raw) */
                view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
                /* channel count */
                view.setUint16(22, numChannels, true);
                /* sample rate */
                view.setUint32(24, 16000, true);
                /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
                view.setUint32(28, 16000 * 4, true);
                /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
                view.setUint16(32, numChannels * 2, true);
                /* bits per sample */
                view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
                /* data chunk identifier */
                writeString(view, 36, 'data');
                /* data chunk length */
                view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

                floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

                return view;
            }
        }, self);
```

Though I have tried to look couple of more option for e.g -**libmp3lame.js** and **ffmpeg** but I don't get to know how do I import these scripts to my ReactJS application because components are made in **JSX** if there is no class in these files how do we use it. We can't use these scripts in **index.html** because then the recorder object mentioned in a component cannot be understandable I hear from people saying there is no difference in JavaScript and ReactJS and it makes me laugh really though I know eventually these code will get transpiled to JavaScript which browser can understand but I can't expect to write JavaScript with no class just ready function and no export and magically expecting to work.

Comment: First, include the script the JS way in index.html. The question is how to use it inside your React code, without the compiler complaining. The answer is to insert a comment like this: `/* global Mp3LameEncoder */` after your `import` lines. You can now use `new Mp3LameEncoder()` in your React classes.

Comment: I assume that's the continuation of previous question. The crucial thing you forgot to mention here is that this is *web worker script*. This changes everything. It seems that currently the issue is the use of non-modular scripts in React, you need to sort this out first of all, that's not specific to MP3 or React. E.g. `lamejs` is modular, you could try it. *I hear from people saying there is no difference in JavaScript and ReactJS* - what you're talking about is the difference between modular and old-fashioned JS. It's not React vs non-React. You don't even use React in this piece of code.

Comment: @ChrisG Add `/* global Mp3LameEncoder */` and import lines inside component?

Comment: @Kramer Yes, in your Component file. I put the comment line after my regular `import` lines. It's not specific to React afaik, but allows to access scripts outside the bundle. You can also use `window.Mp3LameEncoder` instead.

Comment: @ChrisG  if I import these files from public folder inside my component then it says you cannot access public folder inside src

Comment: @estus what I am asking is to just please only one time look at this link https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-browser-audio-capture if I download this zip and use those scriptlets inside index.html then how will I use it inside my component ? I mean how do I even implement it in my reactjs application

Comment: I have no specific advice how to integrate this project with yours, it's not that easy. From what I see, it relies on `webworkify` which requires you to use Browserify, and you cannot do that because it's orthogonal to other bundlers; I suppose you use Webpack. You could possibly try to switch `webworkify` with https://github.com/borisirota/webworkify-webpack but no guarantees. *how will I use it inside my component* - by exchanging messages with a worker. I guess you need to learn how to deal with web workers first, in case you didn't. It seems you're trying to address too many things at once

Comment: It's unclear what's your expertise with web workers. In case you have no experience, I'd suggest to start with React 'hello world' example that uses simple web worker. Then move to an example where you build a worker with Webpack and any third-party module - you will need it later for real things. Only then move to WAVs and MP3s.

Comment: The thing is AWS lex is not giving proper output therefore I wanted to implement there example exactly as they wrote it down and when I downloaded the zip and run the index.html file since it's not reactjs it works(after using credentials of aws)......but I just want it to be implemented in my ReactJS application but it seems I can't easily do it by seeing your comment....Lastly, what I observed is my recording is in stereo and the example they gave is in mono I tried to make it mono but failing it. And I am addressing too many things at once because if something doesnt work I have to try next

Comment: @estus I don't have time to learn web workers now I need to make it work at any cost then once it's done I will take time to learn it

Comment: You will need to learn workers because you actually try to use them and you need to understand what you're doing at least. Otherwise you will have to hire someone to do the job for you. The thing is too complex to finish it by just trial and error. You could try to move whole encoding thing from workers to main thread (i.e. React app) to come up with workable proof of concept but encoding will freeze the thread for many seconds.

Comment: Actually I tried to use the file `aws-lex-audio.js` in my component but....two things is giving error one `self` which I don't know why other is `AWS` variable which I am pretty sure because I need to import somehow my other module `aws-sdk.min.js` but I will reduce my code since I don't want to put it to lex from my reactjs rather from backend therefore I will just remove it

Comment: @estus Lastly when I created reactjs application I created with command create-react-app my-app therefore I don't have webpack config file in my path

Comment: CRA uses Webpack internally. You can eject Webpack configuration in case you need to fine-tune a project (you likely do) with `eject` command, or go with some other way to use workers in CRA app. E.g. https://medium.com/@danilog1905/how-to-use-web-workers-with-react-create-app-and-not-ejecting-in-the-attempt-3718d2a1166b . *Actually I tried to use the file aws-lex-audio.js in my component* - you obviously will need to change some things to make it work.